# Iterating through an unordered multimap

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl

I have inserted some elements in my unordered_multimap and I am finding all the values mapped to a key k using equal range. Now I want to traverse these mapped values by their order of insertion. Look at the code for better understanding.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    unordered_multimap<int,int> m;
    m.insert(make_pair(1,2));
    m.insert(make_pair(1,3));
    m.insert(make_pair(1,4));
    auto it = m.equal_range(1);
    for(auto it1 = it.first; it1 != it.second; it1++) {
        cout<<it1->second<<endl;
    }
}
```

output:

```
4
3
2
```

But I want to traverse in the order in which keys and mapped values were inserted. So, I want to traverse in order 2,3,4. Is it possible?

Comment: No it's not. You'll want to look at boost multi index

Comment: I guess the name made it clear that it's an UNORDERED map. You just can't expect any particular ordering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not a straghtforward way to do what you are asking for. When elements are inserted in an ordered or an unordered multimap they are actually placed in the internal structure and it is not known in which order they have been placed.

You should have an auxiliary e.g. an `std::queue` container for this where you append the iterator to the inserted element. The iterator can be obtained from the insertion as:

`auto inserted_pos =  m.insert(make_pair(1,4));`

Keep in mind that iterators are not invalidated during insertion. They are invalidated if the element is removed, and only for the concerned element.

Answer (score 0):

here's one way to achieve what you want.

It uses a few techniques made available by `boost::multi_index`.

Note the use of `project` to convert iterators in one index to iterators in another.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>

#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/sequenced_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/hashed_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/identity.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/member.hpp>


namespace example {
    struct by_id {};
    struct by_insertion_order {};

    using namespace boost;
    using namespace boost::multi_index;


    using item_type = std::pair<int, int>;

typedef multi_index_container<
    item_type,            // what we are storing
    indexed_by<
        // unordered multimap-type index
        hashed_non_unique<tag<by_id>, member<item_type, int, &item_type::first> >,

        // sequence-type index - records insertion order
        sequenced<tag<by_insertion_order>>
    >
> my_store;

    using const_insertion_sequence_iterator = decltype(std::declval<my_store>().get<by_insertion_order>().cbegin());

    using const_by_id_iterator = decltype(std::declval<my_store>().get<by_id>().cbegin());

    // convert a range of 'by_id' iterators to an ordered vector 'by_insertion_sequence' iterators
    // @param store is a reference to the store for which the iterators are valid
    // @param first is the first by_id iterator in the filtered range
    // @param last is the 'one past the end' iterator of the filtered range
    // @returns a vector of iterators to items ordered by insertion sequence
    auto
    projected_to_insertion_order(const my_store& store,
                                 const_by_id_iterator first,
                                 const_by_id_iterator last)
    -> std::vector<const_insertion_sequence_iterator>
    {
        std::vector<const_insertion_sequence_iterator> result;

        for ( ; first != last ; ++first) {
            result.push_back(store.project<by_insertion_order>(first));
        }

        sort(result.begin(),
             result.end(),
             [&store](const auto& il, const auto& ir) {
                 return distance(store.get<by_insertion_order>().cbegin(), il)
                 < distance(store.get<by_insertion_order>().cbegin(), ir);
             });

        return result;
    }

}


int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    using example::my_store;
    using example::by_id;
    using example::by_insertion_order;
    using example::projected_to_insertion_order;

    // define store
    my_store m;

    // add some items
    m.get<by_id>().emplace(1,2);
    m.get<by_id>().emplace(3,6);
    m.get<by_id>().emplace(1,3);
    m.get<by_id>().emplace(2,5);
    m.get<by_id>().emplace(1,4);

    // get range of items filtered by id
    auto ip = m.get<by_id>().equal_range(1);

    cout << "filtered but unordered\n";
    for (auto it = ip.first ; it != ip.second ; ++it) {
        cout << it->first << ":" << it->second << endl;
    }

    // project that to a vector of iterators to items ordered by insertion sequence

    cout << "filtered and ordered by insertion sequence\n";
    for (const auto& it : projected_to_insertion_order(m, ip.first, ip.second)) {
        cout << it->first << ":" << it->second << endl;
    }
}
```

expected output:

```
filtered but unordered
1:4
1:3
1:2
filtered and ordered by insertion sequence
1:2
1:3
1:4
```